# IntelliJ Swing UI Designer can not scroll

Tags: swing, intellij-idea

I need to scroll down swing form editor to access botom items of the form. but can not select and grab shown scroll bar.
intellij idea 2022.1
[image]

Comment: Could you upload your form file at https://uploads.jetbrains.com and share the UploadID here? It seems like happens because the scrollbar is a part of component like JScrollBar, etc... It does not belong to the form designer itself

Comment: Upload id: 2023_07_26_iyJXpfb1okoH522w6vM4T7 (file: MainFrame.form)

Comment: @EgorKlepikov form uploded

Comment: It is expected in your case because JScrollBar is a part of the form, not the UI designer itself. Clicking to design surface is handled as component selection. You can launch the application to debug JScrollBar behavior and see other components

Comment: @EgorKlepikov I need to access other component in form design screen to manupulate them